# Notebook “Stop My Server” slow to respond (5-10+ seconds) with Kubespawner

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I’m running Jupterhub 0.9.4 with Kubespawner 0.10.1 on RedHat OpenShift 3.11. I’ve observed that the DELETE request sent when you “Stop My Server” routinely takes 5-10 seconds to complete. I’ve included logs below to illustrate this behavior.

I’ve experimented with the various configurable timeouts however none seem to remedy this behavior. Is this consistent with what others are seeing on K8S when terminating pods? Is there a way to configure the event reflector timeout_seconds field?

```
*** jupyterhub logs ***
[D 2020-01-06 19:19:19.099 [ConfigProxy] debug: PROXY WEB /app/jupyter/hub/api/users/iman.administrator/server to http://127.0.0.1:8081 
[I 2020-01-06 19:19:19.118 JupyterHub proxy:264] Removing user iman.administrator from proxy (/app/jupyter/user/iman.administrator/)
[D 2020-01-06 19:19:19.119 JupyterHub proxy:686] Proxy: Fetching DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8082/api/routes/app/jupyter/user/iman.administrator 
19:19:19.121 [ConfigProxy] info: Removing route /app/jupyter/user/iman.administrator
19:19:19.121 [ConfigProxy] info: 204 DELETE /api/routes/app/jupyter/user/iman.administrator 
[I 2020-01-06 19:19:19.122 JupyterHub spawner:1758] Deleting pod jupyterhub-nb-iman-2eadministrator
[D 2020-01-06 19:19:19.618 JupyterHub reflector:263] events watcher timeout
[D 2020-01-06 19:19:19.618 JupyterHub reflector:202] Connecting events watcher
[D 2020-01-06 19:19:24.186 JupyterHub reflector:263] pods watcher timeout
[D 2020-01-06 19:19:24.186 JupyterHub reflector:202] Connecting pods watcher
[D 2020-01-06 19:19:24.221 JupyterHub user:578] Deleting oauth client jupyterhub-user-iman.administrator
[I 2020-01-06 19:19:24.237 JupyterHub base:779] User iman.administrator server took 5.119 seconds to stop
[I 2020-01-06 19:19:24.238 JupyterHub log:158] 204 DELETE /app/jupyter/hub/api/users/iman.administrator/server (iman.administrator@::ffff:xx.xx.xx.xx) 5137.15ms


*** minimal-notebook logs *** 
[I 2020-01-06 19:19:01.266 SingleUserNotebookApp log:158] 200 GET /app/jupyter/user/iman.administrator/api/sessions?_=1578338295737 (iman.administrator@::ffff:xx.xx.xx.xx) 1.98ms
++ kill -TERM 33
+ trap - TERM INT
+ wait 33
[C 2020-01-06 19:19:19.150 SingleUserNotebookApp notebookapp:1523] received signal 15, stopping
[I 2020-01-06 19:19:19.154 SingleUserNotebookApp notebookapp:1643] Shutting down 0 kernels
+ STATUS=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to a newer version of jupyterhub.